# Remove vertical space between text and equations in column alignment

Tags: spacing, equations

Is there a way to remove this large vertical space between my text and equations. I think this problem is a result of my aligning the equations into two columns.This is the code that I am using

```
by the following CES aggregators:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{equation}
C_{O,t}
\end{equation}\break
\begin{equation}
C_{Z,t}
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Can you complete your code so we have a small document we can compile?

Comment: You mean vertical space, I suppose.

Comment: If you want to keep your `multicols`, use `\noindent` as in `by the following CES aggregators:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent
\begin{equation}
C_{O,t}
\end{equation}\columnbreak
\begin{equation}
C_{Z,t}
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you so much for your suggestion! It worked like a breeze.

Comment: @Bernard I am sorry about that. I have made the necessary corrections to my question.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use `minipage`s. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
by the following CES aggregators:

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{equation}
    C_{O,t}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{equation}
    C_{Z,t}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: equations minus spurious space]