# How to display equation number at the right end of the line?

Tags: spacing, equations

I am following the answer to [Gothai Ganan's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262690/remove-vertical-space-between-text-and-equations-in-column-alignment) to a previous question to remove the extra spaces between equations and between equation and text.  It worked great except that the equation number is no longer displayed at the right end of the equation but at the center of the next line.

For example the following code:

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation}\label{Gamma3}
        \Gamma_t  +2 u x\Gamma_x+ w\Gamma_z
        =\mu\left(4x\Gamma_{xx} +\Gamma_{zz}\right)\\
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
```

Displayed the equation number right below `\Gamma_{zz}` at next line.

Qestion:
How to display the equation number at the right end of the same line?

Comment: The width of the minipage is probably not wide enough to accommodate both the equation and the equation number on the same line.  It's not clear why the equatioin is being buried in a minipage.  Providing a small compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` would be more helpful, but additional text saying why you need a minipage would be helpful too.

Comment: never use `\\ ` in `equation`

Answer (score 1):

Three suggestions:

- Get rid of `\left` and `\right`. They're not doing anything useful anyway.
- Snug up the `\Gamma` subscript terms to `\Gamma` via `\!` (negative thinspace) directives.
- Get rid of the spurious `\\` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation}\label{Gamma3}
        \Gamma_{\!t}  +2 u x\Gamma_{\!x}+ w\Gamma_{\!z}
        =\mu(4x\Gamma_{\!xx} +\Gamma_{\!zz})
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```